# Memory validate in difficult task within thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio, vector

I'm currently creating a sound system for my project. Every call PlayAsync creating instance of sound in std::thread callback. The sound data proceed in cycle in this callback. When thread proceeds it store sound instance in static vector. When thread ends (sound complete) - it delete sound instance and decrement instance count. When application ends - it must stop all sounds immediate, sending interrupt to every cycle of sound.

The problem is in array keeping these sounds. I am not sure, but I think vector isn't right choice for this purpose.. Here is a code.

```
void gSound::PlayAsync()
{
    std::thread t(gSound::Play,mp_Audio,std::ref(*this));
    t.detach();
}
    HRESULT gSound::Play(IXAudio2* s_XAudio,gSound& sound)
{                
    gSound* pSound = new gSound(sound);   
    pSound->m_Disposed = false;         

    HRESULT hr;      
    // Create the source voice
    IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice;
    if( FAILED( hr = s_XAudio->CreateSourceVoice( &pSourceVoice, pSound->pwfx ) ) )
    {
        gDebug::ShowMessage(L"Error creating source voice");      
        return hr;
    }

    // Submit the wave sample data using an XAUDIO2_BUFFER structure
    XAUDIO2_BUFFER buffer = {0};
    buffer.pAudioData = pSound->pbWaveData;
    buffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;  // tell the source voice not to expect any data after this buffer
    buffer.AudioBytes = pSound->cbWaveSize;

    if( FAILED( hr = pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer( &buffer ) ) )
    {
        gDebug::ShowMessage(L"Error submitting source buffer");
        pSourceVoice->DestroyVoice();   
        return hr;
    }

    hr = pSourceVoice->Start( 0 );     

    // Let the sound play
    BOOL isRunning = TRUE;
    m_soundInstanceCount++;     
    mp_SoundInstances.push_back(pSound); #MARK2
    while( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && isRunning && pSourceVoice != nullptr && !pSound->m_Interrupted)
    {    
        XAUDIO2_VOICE_STATE state;
        pSourceVoice->GetState( &state );
        isRunning = ( state.BuffersQueued > 0 ) != 0;     
        Sleep(10);
    }   
    pSourceVoice->DestroyVoice();   
    delete pSound;pSound = nullptr; //its correct ??
    m_soundInstanceCount--; 
    return 0;    
}

void gSound::InterrupAllSoundInstances()
{
    for(auto Iter = mp_SoundInstances.begin(); Iter != mp_SoundInstances.end(); Iter++)
    {
        if(*Iter != nullptr)//#MARK1
        {
        (*Iter)->m_Interrupted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And this I call in application class before disposing sound objects, after main application loop immediate.

```
    gSound::InterrupAllSoundInstances();
while (gSound::m_soundInstanceCount>0)//waiting for deleting all sound instances in threads
{

}
```

Questions:

So #MARK1 - How to check memory validation in vector? I don't have experience about it. And get errors when try check invalid memory (it's not equals null)

And #MARK2 - How to use vector correctly? Or maybe vector is bad choice? Every time I create sound instance it increases size. It's not good.

Comment: You have to serialize the access to resources shared by several threads in parallel.  You use `Mutexes` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927(v=vs.85).aspx) for this purpose.  Also, checkout - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021164/how-can-i-protect-a-vector-with-a-mutex

Comment: I read about mutexes that they are used for interoperate between multiply threads. But I create a separate threads, for every sound instance, without cross between them.

Comment: The cross is the Vector, it is accessed by more than one thread at a time.  When two threads access the vector (could be even one for reading and one for writing), the state of the vector might not be defined (when trying to read, the underlying data structure might be in the muddle of a change for the ongoing inset / push_back).

Comment: I will improve knowledge about mutex. But anyway, does I check vector element correct ? "if(*Iter != nullptr)"

Comment: The vector will be valid, it wasn't disallocated.  But imagine that the vector can change between your call to `Iter++` (which moves inside the vector's data structure) and until you checked for its value which might render `*Iter` useless / non-existent.  Every access to a shared resource must be serialized = make sure only one thread can access the shared resource at any given moment (Mutext / Critical Section).

Comment: Hmm.. I call code with Iter++ after application loop. So I cannot create another sound thread when InterrupAllSoundInstances happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical issue:

```
delete pSound;
pSound = nullptr; // issue
```

This does not do what you think.

It will effectively set `pSound` to null, but there are other copies of the same pointer too (at least one in the vector) which do not get nullified. This is why you do not find `nullptr` in your `vector`.

Instead you could register the index into the vector and nullify that: `mp_SoundInstances[index] = nullptr;`.

However, I am afraid that you simply do not understand memory handling well and you lack structure. For memory handling, it's hard to tell without details and your system seems complicated enough that I am afraid it would tell too long to explain. For structure, you should read a bit about the `Observer` pattern.